# Connect BeagleBone Black to Internet

Tags: iptables, beagleboneblack

I am trying to use this tutorial to connect to the internet from the BeagleBone Black: https://elementztechblog.wordpress.com/2014/12/22/sharing-internet-using-network-over-usb-in-beaglebone-black/

The IpTables steps do not seem to yield the correct configuration. For example:

iptables --table nat -A POSTROUTING -o wlp2s0 -j MASQUERADE

creates the following configuration:

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
MASQUERADE  all  --  localhost/16         anywhere
MASQUERADE  all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Why do I have anywhere as destination when I clearly specify wlp2s0 ? Can anyone please help ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`iptables -t nat -L` doesn't seem to show additional information like interfaces.

While it's meant to be for save/restore and machine-readable, I much prefer the output of `iptables-save` due to its completeness.

In your case this should show you the complete configuration for the "nat" table:

`iptables-save -t nat`

Comment: Thanks ! This displays a completely different result!